# Unable to create instance of Cloud Object Storage

Tags: devops, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage, coursera-api

I am taking the devops course on Coursera, and one of the course assignment is to create an instance of Cloud Storage Object.

So I already had a little bit of trouble verifying, after a really long time of playing around, I finally able to get the the creating page.

I chose IBM Cloud as the infrastructure and lite plan, but the create button is greyed out and I have no idea what else I can do.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Are you logged in? Have you configured the other fields below what you are showing?

Comment: The lite plan only allows one instance. Maybe you already have one